# jQuery - Unspecified token . - what's unspecified?

Tags: javascript, jquery, token

I'm currently trying to get a click if statement to work that will detect if one link has been clicked. If it hasn't been clicked before, then ignore the click but then set the variable to true to say it has been clicked before.

***However***, I then need the second link with the class `.stopper` to essentially reset the variable to false regardless so that the first button will require two clicks again. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var hasClick = false;

    if('a').click(function(e)) {
        if('a').hasClass('stopper') {
            e.preventDefault();
            var hasClick = false;
        } else {
            if(hasClick == false) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var hasClick = true;
            }
        }
    }

});
```

I'm getting an `Unspecified token .` error after this line `if('a').click(function(e)) {` (line 5, the third line of actual code).

What's wrong here? The other questions I've with this kind of error don't seem to fit with the code I have, in the sense of the kind of functions etc.

This semi helped me under the unspecified token section but still no luck on how to fix it. http://davidwalsh.name/fix-javascript-errors

So an example of this working would be:

*hasClick variable is false.*

*Button 1 : click me once and set variable (hasClick) to true but ignore the link, so don't go anywhere the first time I'm clicked. Once the variable is true then go to the link.*

*Button 2 : regardless of whether the variable is true or not, make sure it's false and ignore the click.*

- ***EDIT***

For example, this is what the menu looks like:

```
Level 0 Link
  Level 1 Link
  Level 1 Link
    Level 2 Link
    Level 2 Link
      Level 3 Link
      Level 3 Link
Level 0 Link
  Level 1 Link
  Level 1 Link
    Level 2 Link
    Level 2 Link
      Level 3 Link
      Level 3 Link

$(document).ready(function () {

    var hasClick = false;

    $( '.level-0 a' ).on('click', function(e) {
        if( $( this ).hasClass('.level-0 a')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            hasClick = false;
        } else {
            if(hasClick == false) {
                e.preventDefault();
                hasClick = true;
            } else {
                return true;
                hasClick = true;
            }
        }
    });

});
```

So when you click the first level 0 link, it works! Great. But when you decide you also want to click the second level 0 link, it doesn't stop the link from being activated and going to that page like it did with the first level 0 link.

Comment: yes missing ( after if

Comment: I suggest you read up on if-statements and how they work in Javascript. It also seems like you might have misunderstod how you bind to a click event in jQuery.

Comment: Also it seem that you re-initialise you variable `hasClick` by using `var`. When you say `var hasClick = something` you overwrite your previous variable and create a new one under the same name. I would recommend removing the two `var` keywords in the click function.

Comment: try to develop a better idea about the syntax and global/local variables in javascript.

Comment: I'm semi new to jQuery and to be fair this use case is not a usual example.  I was just trying things out to see where I was slipping up.

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax errors and other misunderstanding of the syntax in your 
code.

**The changes made are**

1. Moved `var hasClick = false;` outside the `document ready`.
2. `$('a').on('click',function(e){` instead of `if('a').click(function(e))`
3. Used `$(this)` instead of `$('a')` inside the handler.
4. Variable value change inside is made to just `hasClick = false;`, because it is a global variable, if you use `var hasClick` inside the function it is simply a local variable.

```js
var hasClick = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('stopper')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      hasClick = false;
    } else {
      if (hasClick == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
        hasClick = true;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried this method and it prevent all links from being clicked. Regardless of how many times you click it doesn't activate the link.

Comment: @ow_dj so you want all the links to be disabled at first, and enable them when we click second time?

Comment: Yes, if possible. I've updated the question with my current code that works (ish) but doesn't seem to work across a whole menu. I'll explain above.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your function should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hasClick = false;
    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        if( $(this).hasClass('stopper') ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var hasClick = false;
        } 
        else {
            if(hasClick == false) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var hasClick = true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```